# OCR not recognizing the contents of Camera pic?

Tags: android, ocr

i am trying to develop an OCR app, which will recognize the content of Camera pic , but getting a response "This Image Is too Big",i tried to resize the image,,, but still not happening. My code of OCR is this

```
public class weocr {

String response;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private String selectedpath;


weocr(String selectedpath) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, ParseException,     ClientProtocolException, IOException
{
   String url="http://appsv.ocrgrid.org/cgi-bin/weocr/submit_tesseract.cgi";
   response="";
   this.selectedpath=selectedpath;
   HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
   client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
   HttpPost post=new HttpPost(url);
   MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity( HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE );


   //test start
   try {
       File imgFile = new  File(selectedpath);
       int h = 200; // height in pixels
       int w = 200; // width in pixels    

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
 Bitmap bm1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, h, w, true);     
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);
    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
    ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "testbin.png");


  //test end
      entity.addPart( "userfile", bab);

    // For usual String parameters
    entity.addPart( "outputencoding", new StringBody("utf-8"));
    entity.addPart( "outputformat", new StringBody("txt"));
    post.setEntity( entity );
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
    String sResponse;
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

    while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        s = s.append(sResponse);
    }


    this.response=new String(s.toString());

    //System.out.println("Response: " + s);

   // Here we go!
   //String response = EntityUtils.toString( client.execute( post ).getEntity(), "UTF-8" );
   //client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
   //System.out.println(response);
   //Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    //toast.show();


   }


   catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
   }

 }






}
```

Comment: I think you would be better addressing this problem to the support desk at ocrgrid.org

Comment: Have you contacted ocrgrid.org to get their API? What image sizes are supported?

Comment: No, i dont think like that,,,, The thing i have noticed that the pic taken by camera was about 2.5 MB in size, so it will be better to cut short the size (not about the content in the pic) and then send the result